# UINavigationController -- can't get started

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having terrible trouble trying to get a navigation controller up-and-running.

Basically, I want to be able to push new views to the controller and hit the back button, etc.

Here is the code I have sofar:

TestAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

TestAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}

@end
```

But what do I do now?

I mean where do I put the .xib file that holds the NavigationController?

Comment: what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Your code so far is an empty iOS project. :|

Comment: Xcode 4.2 Don't want to use storyboards as I have never used them before

Comment: You know you can use the latest Xcode, without using StoryBoards...

Comment: Wehere is navigation controller?

Comment: I don't know where to put it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your viewcontroller first (New File > UIViewController subclass > check With Xib for user interface)

Then setup your `UINavigationController`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: OK, I did that and it seems to work, but I'd like to get back buttons and so forth. Isn't that a UINavigationController? Shouldn't I have to put one of them in one of my xibs somewhere?

Comment: You only get à back button in your navigation bar if you from your ViewController pushes another view controller on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [`UINavigationController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Linked within are several sample projects that utilize a navigation controller. Feel free to download them and look through them for how you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the storyboard feature in xcode. It makes this as easy as dragging and dropping a NavigationController onto the storyboard.

This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just find a tutorial and run through it. Like this one:

http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-4-navigation-controller/

Answer (score 0):

create New File > UIViewController subclass > check With Xib for user interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class WhatEverFileNameClass
@interface TestAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) WhatEverFileNameClass *viewController;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[WhatEverFileNameClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"WhatEverFileNameClass" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I don't really understand this. Why are you using a viewController when it's a navigationcontroller I need?